# Close all tabs to right of current tab with JavaScript or greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, tabs, automation, greasemonkey, bots

I'm currently coding a bot to do something for me and currently it has to open a large number of tabs every iteration and to make the bot fully automatic I have to find a way to close them all except the original the bot is running from. (The tabs have to be closed before the next iteration or what it's doing fails.)

Comment: You could potentially do that with a webdriver-based tool (e.g. selenium, watir-webdriver).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to actually do this using a function that would detect the URL and do a specific function for that and then close it. Here's the code...

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("https://www.google.com") != -1) {
```

So this detects that my URL contains a certain string and therefore activates on all pages after this URL. It works for what I want.

Answer (score 1):

- Not possible generally via userscripts because modern browsers block the attempts to close tabs/windows (Firefox has a config value to allow it but not all users would be willing to enable it). You will have to convert the userscript to an extension/addon.
- In case you don't mind changing the default browser config to allow scripts to close tabs, use `GM_setValue` to raise a flag that will be periodically checked by your script in other tabs:

  ```
  var dontCloseMe = false;

  setInterval(function() {
      var shouldClose = Date.now() - GM_getValue("terminate", 0) < 2 * 100;
      if (shouldClose && !dontCloseMe) {
          window.close();
      }
  }, 100);

  .................

  if (shouldCloseOtherTabs) {
      dontCloseMe = true;
      GM_setValue("terminate", Date.now());
  }
  ```

  And make sure the `// @include` actually includes the urls of those other tabs.

Comment: The bot is opening the tabs though so actually it is aloud to close them and if it isn't I can just change the settings in about:config

Comment: @Taazar, new GreaseMonkey doesn't return a `window` object from [GM_openInTab](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_openInTab). However it can be circumvented. I'll add an example.

Comment: If I made a list of the tabs as I opened them would I be able to close them all again using the list

Comment: As of Greasemonkey 3.0 GM_openInTab returns `undefined` so you won't have a window object to close directly, but it can be circumvented somehow I think using something similar to this GM_getValue trick.